# Excel: Top 5 rows and combine the rest

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm using pivot tables and I need to get the top 5 rows and then combine the rest in a single row, after the 5th and before the grand total row (shown below).

[image: Table Example]

Is there a way of doing this?

At the moment the "Other" and "Total" rows are manually added but are overwritten or orphaned if the size of the pivot table's data set changes and needs too much maintenance every time it's refreshed.

**EDIT**: I should have mentioned, the pivot tables are generated from a single data source from a separate, which is used on multiple other tabs.

Comment: You could use the function `GetPivotData` to build that table : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GETPIVOTDATA-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f
I'm not sure that can tune enough the pivot table to it directly, but I might be wrong! ;)

Comment: Are the classes static, or based in order descending order of total? -  You could have a separate pivot which lists the top 5 classes by rank.  Then a formula in the main table to see if that class appears in the top 5.  If it does, return the class name, if it doesn't, then return "Other".

Comment: Yeah the data comes form a dataTable in another tab that is the result of a stored proc which returns individual records that have a class field.

Comment: After researching it there's something called PowerPivot which is included in previous and future version of Excel as standard but is only part of stand alone and professional for 2013.

As a work around I calculated what percentage of the total is shown in the chart and displayed it in a text box on top of the chart.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could have a separate pivot which lists the top 5 classes by rank.

Then you need a formula in the main table to see if that class appears in the top 5.  If it does, return the class name, if it doesn't, then return "Other".  Use that as the grouping in the main pivot.

Comment: Is there no way of doing it in just the one table? It's a report with 10 tabs, 25 tables in each, most of which have the "Other" row in them. So it'd be a lot of duplication if not.